# jQuery colorbox not loading on document.ready

Tags: jquery, asp.net, colorbox

I am trying to use jQuery colorbox, but it doesn't work.
Inside an asp gridView I have the following link:

```
<a class="alert_info" href="#alertWin10">View details</a>
```

I have this HTML:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<div id='alertWin10' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
    some content
</div>
```

and this js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".alert_info").colorbox({ inline: true, width: "50%" });
        });
```

then I click on the link it doesn't show the colorbox, instead it just adds "#alertWin10" to the page url, BUT (and this is a big BUT) if I take the line from the document ready (`$(".alert_info").colorbox({ inline: true, width: "50%" });`) and put it in the chrome console and than click on the link, then it does work...
I have no idea how to approach this bug.

Comment: No error in console? Isn't `.alert_info` element added to the DOM after document is ready? Test it using `$(function(){console.log($('.alert_info').length);});`

Comment: it returns 0.... why ???

Comment: Here is something else, if I add a plain html with the same class out side of the grid it somehow works... what is happening ?

Comment: I'm not an ASP guy. It looks like the element is rendered after the document is ready. I added the specific TAG to the question

Comment: If so, than why if I add an html input outside of the gridview fixes it ?

Comment: Because the DOM element exists at time the document is ready. Maybe just replace ready handler with window onload event but again, I'm not an ASP guy, i have no idea what's going on and anyway i have no idea how do you render the gridview

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jquery 1.5.14 to enable colorbox

Comment: I have included the jQuery files, besides it works after I put it in the chrome console.